# Is it better to cycle my laptop battery between 90-100% daily, or to leave it at 50% if running off AC power?

Tags: laptop, battery, power-management

I use my laptop mainly running off of AC power. I would like to keep my battery as healthy as possible, even if it is just a little bit, because neither of the below options hurt me in any way.

Apple recently released a software update with a "battery health management feature" which seemingly cycles 90-100% on the MacBook battery every day.

There is software for the MacBook as well, such as [Al Dente](https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente) and [Charge Limiter](https://github.com/godly-devotion/charge-limiter) which allows you to limit the charging of your battery. At your specified charge level, the laptop will stop charging and run off of AC power.

Given these two options, which one should I go for? Which one would be better for my battery's longevity? Assuming I'm find with both options, of course.

The information in System Information > Hardware > Power is:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you see in System Information > Hardware > Power?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/Lv56P8p) are the most relevant bits, although I'm not sure it's that relevant to the question.

Comment: I would recommend letting it stay at 50% because that is probably the best way to keep your charge cycles low. If I remember correctly, the fewer charge cycles, the better.

Comment: Batteries are just a container of chemicals which inexorably deteriorate upon first use.  I make sure my laptop is fully charged before turning it off for the night. Then I use it on battery until down to about 25% and then charge it again. A good battery lasts about 3 years give or take.

Comment: @Todd I would tend to agree, but I'm also wondering if there any any nuances I'm missing. In any case though having a low cycle count does increase resale value, so I guess I'm more interested in that

Comment: @SkeletonBow For a new battery, which yours seems to be, I think it's best to keep it at 50% and keep it on AC power as much as possible. This will increase battery life, performance, and lower charge cycles.

Comment: An excellent test is to (a) determine the manufacturer's spec for battery life from a full charge when new. Then (b) what are you getting. I find about 60 to 70% at about three years and then I plan on a replacement in the fourth year.

Comment: Expanding on @Todd's comment, manufacturer's recommendation for long term storage is at 50% charge https://www.ineltro.ch/media/downloads/SAAItem/45/45958/36e3e7f3-2049-4adb-a2a7-79c654d92915.pdf so it would make sense keep charge at this level. More cycles = more degradation. (Of course, if you have a power cut, you may regret this decision).

Comment: For lithium-ion batteries it is suggested to recycle between 40-90%.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?